# Структура классов Exception

Tags: php

Реализую интеграцию с 1С. 
Файловая структура такая:

```
classes/
    Integration/
        Intgr_1c/
            Import/
                *.php
            Export/
                *.php
        Intgr_OtherSystem/
```

Хочу реализовать иерархию исключений (базовый класс Exception для интеграции, наследники - интеграции с конкретной системой, наследники - импорт/экспорт).

Директории - неймспейсы.

Не пойму где правильнее расположить классы Exception. 
Создать отельную папку, и там реализовать все экзепшены (базовый и наследники) ?

Или в каждой директории свои?

Например:

```
classes/
    BaseExcetion.php

    Integration/
        IntegrationException.php

        Intgr_1c/
            Integration1CException.php

            Import/
                Integration1C_ImportException.php

                *.php
            ...
```

Comment: Никто не знает?(

Comment: да без разницы как, лишь бы работал автолоад https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Comment: У меня psr-4)))